# Implement a graph structure in Rust

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to represent a graph in Rust using the type:

```rust
struct Node<'a> {
    edges: Vec<&'a Node<'a>>,
}
type Graph<'a> = Vec<Node<'a>>;
```

A `Graph` has the constraint that all the nodes point at other nodes in the same vector. I can create a singleton graph:

```rust
fn createSingleton<'a>() -> Graph<'a> {
    let mut items: Graph<'a> = Vec::new();
    items.push(Node { edges: Vec::new() });
    return items;
}
```

But when I try and create a graph with two nodes, where one points at the other:

```rust
fn createLink<'a>() -> Graph<'a> {
    let mut items: Graph<'a> = Vec::new();
    items.push(Node { edges: Vec::new() });
    items.push(Node { edges: vec![&items[0]] });
    return items;
}
```

I get an error:

```
cannot borrow `items` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
```

In particular the `&items[0]` is an immutable borrow, and the second `items.push` seems to be a mutable borrow. Is it possible to construct the memory layout I desire? If so, how?

Comment: You cannot do like that. Use `Vec<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>`

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios - thanks - as the `Graph` type or the `edges` type? Or should they both have that type?

Comment: And any way without going to `RefCell`, which I believe loses the safety guarantees I'd like from Rust?

Comment: See also [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423)

Comment: @NeilMitchell `RefCell` does not lose the safety guarantees, but it does move them from compile time to run time.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as more than one structure can point to one of your Nodes, you'll lose the "one owner" world of Rust's memory guarantees, and you'll either need something like an Rc, or more esoterically, a weakref. I totally suggest reading https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/ to learn the many ins and outs of this territory.

Comment: That's a great link!